# MSGraph Powershell New-MgDriveItemChild

Tags: azure, powershell, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, drive

I'm trying to use the Microsoft Graph Powershell module to create a a folder in a Sharepoint site's drive.

Looking at the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-post-children?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=powershell) I should be able to do the following:

```
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Files

$params = @{
    name = "New Folder"
    folder = @{
    }
    "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior" = "rename"
}

New-MgDriveItemChild -DriveId $driveId -DriveItemId $driveItemId -BodyParameter $params
```

However, this is giving me an error:

```
New-MgDriveItemChild_Create: You must provide either a file facet if creating a file or a folder facet if creating a folder or a remoteItem facet if adding a shared folder

Status: 400 (BadRequest)
ErrorCode: invalidRequest
Date: 2023-11-23T17:50:50
```

I have got the driveitem ID of the subfolder from the site's shared drive but it will not create the folder? I can use postman ok to create the folder directly via the API, but Powershell doesn't seem to like it.

Maybe my misunderstanding, but what is meant by a folder facet?

Comment: See following for examples of facets : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/onedrive-addressing-driveitems#examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The error occurs if missed including **folder facet** while creating folder using Microsoft Graph PowerShell modules.

When I ran your script to create new folder without defining folder facet, I too **same error** as below:

```
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Files

$params = @{
    name = "New Folder"
    folder = @{
    }
    "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior" = "rename"
}

$driveId = "xxxxxxx"
$driveItemId = "xxxxxxxx"

New-MgDriveItemChild -DriveId $driveId -DriveItemId $driveItemId -BodyParameter $params
```

**Response:**

[image]

> To **resolve** the error, you need to define at least one folder property like **`childCount`** or **`view`** or any property in the request body while creating folder with **New-MgDriveItemChild** cmdlet.

When I ran below **modified** PowerShell script by including **folder facet**, I got response like this:

```
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Files

$params = @{
    name = "New Folder"
    folder = @{
        "childCount" = 1024
        "view" = @{
            "@odata.type" = "microsoft.graph.folderView"
        }
    }
    "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior" = "rename"
}

$driveId = "xxxxxxx"
$driveItemId = "xxxxxxxx"

New-MgDriveItemChild -DriveId $driveId -DriveItemId $driveItemId -BodyParameter $params
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **confirm** that, I checked the same in OneDrive where **new folder** is created successfully as below:

[image]

**Reference:**
[Folder - Microsoft Graph v1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/folder?view=graph-rest-1.0)

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I'm curious regarding the ChildCount though, If this is set to 0 it still works, but I see in the documentation it says 1024, does it matter? Child Count = "Number of children contained immediately within this container." If you are not adding items to the folder in the same call, does this need to be set to a certain size/number?

Comment: That does n't matter. 1024 is the maximum number of children that you can add inside the folder. It's not a mandatory parameter. You can also create folder with just `view` property to make it as folder facet.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like a bug in the PowerShell SDK and in case of empty folder property, the PowerShell SDK just ignores the property and doesn't include it in the request body.

As a workaround, add some fake property to `folder`. It will ensure that the `folder` property is included in the request body.

```
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Files

$params = @{
    name = "New Folder"
    folder = @{
        # fake property to ensures that PowerShell SDK will include folder facet
        x = 'x'
    }
    "@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior" = "rename"
}

New-MgDriveItemChild -DriveId $driveId -DriveItemId $driveItemId -BodyParameter $params
```

I've reported the [bug](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-powershell/issues/2463). Not sure how long it will take until they will fix it.